# Image caching at server side

Tags: image, caching, server-side

For a product catalog web application created in java/spring, which gets the product images from a third party web service, what would be a good strategy for image caching at server side ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have your site create IMG references that point to a locally hosted page. This page will do the following:

```
if (the requested image does not exist in the local cache) {
    go to the third party site and save it to the local cache
}
serve the image from the local cache
```

Depending on how often the images are likely to change on the third party site, you may want to add a cron job that routinely deletes images which are older than X days.

Comment: Thanks.We do persist the image url in the mongodb. But currently fetch the actual images from the 3rd party service. You're right, the simplest cache would be like the one you have mentioned.